# Error while creating a closure inside a function

Tags: swift

Thanks a lot for the reply. It's true that I am learning to write closures at this stage. Actually I read somewhere about the "forEach" function that works on collections and that takes a single argument as parameter (i.e a closure).

Syntax of forEach is "Void forEach(body: (Int) throws -> Void) rethrows"

What I am trying to do is write a similar function with a single parameter (i.e a closure) that will calculate the Factorial of a number and so we can print the Factorial of that number. I don't want to pass that number as a second parameter to that function.

I understand that forEach is a member function of Collections class that works on each element one by one. So it picks up the elements from within the array. Similarly I have created a private property (factorialNumber) inside my class (whose value I can set using the public function "setFactorialNumber"). Now I am trying to create a public function (factorial) for my class that will have only one parameter (i.e the closure) that will use the value of "factorialNumber" property internally and calculate the factorial of that number that we can print from outside when we call that function from the other code.

Below is my class..

```
public class MyArray {
    private var factorialNumber = 0

    public func setFactorialNumber(factorialNumber value: Int) {
        factorialNumber = value
    }

    public func factorial(body closure: (Int) -> Void) -> Void {
        var outputString: String?
        var result = 1

        if factorialNumber <= 0 {
            outputString = nil
        } else {
            outputString = ""
            while(factorialNumber >= 1) {
                if factorialNumber == 1 {
                    outputString = outputString! +  "\(factorialNumber) = \(result)"
                    break
                } else {
                    outputString = outputString! + "\(factorialNumber) x "
                }
                result = result * factorialNumber
                factorialNumber -= 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question indicates little to no knowledge of closures. Please read up on the concept and understand the purpose of closures. From what I can see in your question, you only need a function (no closures). Closures serve a different purpose to what you seem to be trying to achieve

Comment: Not related to programming, but if you plan on using this for actual math you should note that 0 is also a valid input (0! = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure is basically a function that wants to be called.
In your case, you're defining it but you're not using it.

Problems I see in `factorial(body:)`:

1. You should execute the closure atleast once.
   i.e. do the following at some point/s:

   ```
   closure(someValue)
   ```
2. You seem to maintain an `outputString`, which looks like the thing you want the closure to take.
   In this case, your closure should take a `String` instead of an `Int`.

   ```
   func factorial(body closure: (String?) -> Void) -> Void { //...
   ```

Finally, this is what the function should look like:

```
func factorial(body closure: (String?) -> Void) -> Void {
    var outputString: String?

    //...your factorial logic as:
    if factorialNumber <= 0 {
        outputString = nil
    } else {
        outputString = ""
        while(factorialNumber >= 1) {
            if factorialNumber == 1 {
                outputString = outputString! +  "\(factorialNumber) = \(result)"
                break
            } else {
                outputString = outputString! + "\(factorialNumber) x "
            }
            result = result * factorialNumber
            factorialNumber -= 1
        }
    }

    //Finally, the closure call
    closure(outputString)
}
```

---

And looking at your structure, it's usage will be:

```
let factorial = MyArray()
factorial.setFactorialNumber(factorialNumber: 20)
factorial.factorial { (result) in
    print(result)
}
```

It's output is:

> 20 x 19 x 18 x 17 x 16 x 15 x 14 x 13 x 12 x 11 x 10 x 9 x 8 x 7 x 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 2432902008176640000

---

#### NOTE: Your class is Crashable

The answer above is sufficient for the particular context of your question but duly note:

1. Your logic uses `Int`, so numbers higher than 20 cause your code to crash

   **Solution:**

   - Use `Double`
   - Guard your logic from crashing on inputs too large to handle
2. If you don't `setFactorialNumber(factorialNumber:)`, and directly jump to calling `factorial(body:)`, your code will crash.

---

#### Improvement?:

- Change classname from `MyArray` to `FactorialFinder` or something
- Add an `init` to this class:

  ```
  init(with number: Int) {
      self.factorialNumber = number
  }
  ```
- Now that we have a custom init, make the default `init` private:

  ```
  private init() {}
  ```

  - So something like this is not possible `FactorialFinder()`
  - And `FactorialFinder(with:)` becomes the only way to initialize this class

Comment: Than you sooo much for the help buddy. I tried the solution, but the output that I get in the playground is: ()

arr1.setFactorialNumber(number: 5)
arr1.factorial{ (result) in
    print(result ?? "Result is Nil")
}

Output: ()

Comment: Thank you soo much for the reply. I have used the solution that you provided. But the output that I get in playground is:

Comment: @vermau Check again. I confirmed it in playground before posting an answer. You may have missed something. Btw, I've updated answer including your factorial logic.

Comment: Hello dear, I have uploaded my file on dropbox and here is the link. Can you please see what's going wrong. It is a very small file. Thanks in anticipation.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tctncxbx3nbq57z/Factorial.zip?dl=0

Comment: @vermau I ran your playground setup and it's output is `5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120`. Looks fine to me except for all those `arr1.insert(value:)` that don't really make sense to me.

Comment: Those are just some practice things I was trying. My custom class has an array inside and insert is just a custom method to append values in the internal array. These are just for practice.

I am using Xcode 9.4. When I run this code the output I get is (). This is very strange

Comment: @vermau The `()` output is on the right-hand side. For `print` logs you need to look at the console. Use hotkey `Shift+Cmd+C` to bring up the console.

Comment: Oh my god!.I didn't notice that. The result was in the console mixed up with other results. How stupid of me. Sorry, my bad dear. But thank you soooo much for helping me out with this..

Just one more thing that I am curious about is that I wanted to create a function like array.forEach which does not pass any parameter inside the closure, but we are passing one parameter inside the closure.

Syntax for array.forEach...
`arr1.forEach {
print("$0")
}`

Comment: @vermau If I understand your new requirement correctly then it seems you want to loop through your array and generate the factorial result for each item. If that is the case then you would no longer need `setFactorialNumber(factorialNumber:)`, and your `factorial(body:)` logic would change considerably.

Comment: @vermau I suggest you to post a new question regarding it because adding content **now** would just change the context of this question and the above answer would be obsolete and get longer and complicated to keep up. Keep your problems concise so you get concise answers :)

Comment: No no I don't want to calculate the factorial of every number inside the array. Just one number i.e factorialNumber. I just want to create a function like forEach that takes a close as parameter, but nothing is passed inside the closure as parameter. But I will post a new question for this. Thanks a lot dear

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is a good hint of your problem:

```
factorial {
 print("Factorial is: \($0)")
}
```

What is the **exact text** that you want this function to print? "Factorial is: 100", "Factorial is: 200"?

This is a trick question, because the answer is unknowable: your function doesn't accept a number to calculate the factorial from, it only accepts a trailing closure that defines what to do with the result.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the reply. It's true that I am learning to write closures at this stage. Actually I read somewhere about the "forEach" function that works on collections and that takes a single argument as parameter (i.e a closure).Syntax of forEach is "Void forEach(body: (Int) throws -> Void) rethrows"

Comment: Yes, but `forEach` is an array method, which allows it to operate on the contents of the array. It's `array.forEach { print($0) }`, where the closure body is repeated with each element of `array`; not `forEach { print($0) }`, which doesn't have anything that it can obviously operate on.

Comment: Hi you are so prompt.. amazing. I have just added my whole class code in the section above and also explained what I am trying to achieve. Please see if you can help me resolve my problem. I have been trying to solve this for two days now